# how to moving data with raddioButton to another activity

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

i want to if i chose one of my RadioButton it will show String in another activity, how to slove this?
this is stuck my study for my school, if you have best way that can help me, in other web always using Toast for example RadioButton, that cant help me full

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dateFormatter = new  SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    tvDataResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedDate);
    btDataPicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btndate);

    btDataPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDateDialog();
        }
    });

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.planets_array,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    final EditText edtNama = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNama);
    final EditText edtNim =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNim);
    tvDataResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSelectedDate);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTampilkan);

    final RadioGroup rbg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgroup);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nama = edtNama.getText().toString();
            String nim = edtNim.getText().toString();
            String date = tvDataResult.getText().toString();

            int selectedId = rbg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            rblaki=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            rbcewe=(RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Nama",nama);
            intent.putExtra("NIM",nim);
            intent.putExtra("tanggal",date);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my XML. i only show this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Jenis Kelamin"
    android:textSize="17dp" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rgroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rblaki"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Laki-laki" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rbcewe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Perempuan" />
</RadioGroup>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTampilkan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TAMPILKAN" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DELETE" />
```

[I want to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyPfD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice to do this, it is creating a Class implementing Serializable to pass to another Activity or Fragment using Bundle extras (the way to pass an object to another screen).

**Step 1 - Object example: Remember to add the gets and setters**

```
   public class Person implements Serializable { 
      private String nama; 
      private String nim;
      private String date;
  }
```

**Step 2 - Passing the object to another activity**

```
    ....
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("objParameter", obj); // obj is your class serializable
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

**Step 3 - Getting the object into ResultActivity**

```
      //Inside onCreate() method
      Person personParam = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("objParameter");
```

Notes: Make sure if you are implementing Serializable in your class or inner class :)